# Run every test for a single instance of @DataProvider using a @Factory

Tags: java, selenium, testing, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have a test class with about 5+ tests in it that I want to run once for each url sequentially.  For example:

> URL 1 From @DataProvider:
> Test 1: Pass
> Test 2: Fail
> Test 3: Fail
> Test 4: Pass
> URL 2 From @DataProvider:
> Test 1: Pass
> Test 2: Fail
> Test 3: Fail
> Test 4: Pass

Instead of how it is currently:

> URL 1:
> Test 1: Pass
> URL 2:
> Test 1: Pass
> URL 1:
> Test 2: Fail
> URL 2:
> Test 2: Fail
> etc.

I'm pulling the URLs from an excel sheet in my DataProvider like so:

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] urlDataProvider() throws Exception {
    File file = new File("ExampleClients.xlsx");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("URL's");

    int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    Object[][] urlData = new Object[rowCount+1][1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= rowCount; i++) {
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
        XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);
        String URL = cell.getStringCellValue();
        urlData[i][0] = URL;
    }
    return urlData;
}
```

I've tried using a @Factory but am new to the whole QA/TestNG and am confused by it:

```
@Factory(dataProvider="urlDataProvider")
public CareFirstTests(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
```

All of my test methods, @Factory and @DataProvider are in the same java test file.
When I try using the Factory I get this error

> Couldn't find a constructor in class

I'm also open to hearing any other ways how to accomplish something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no restrictions to convert your tests into individual methods, the above ask can be achieved using below approach. Let me know if this helps.

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class StackTest {
    
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] returnData(){
        return new Object [][]{{"Input 1"}, {"Input 2"}};
    }
    
    @Test(dataProvider="returnData")
    public void iterativeTest(String val) {
        System.out.println("This is from returned Data : "+ val);
        dp1(val);
        dp2(val);
    }
    
    public void dp1(String val) {
        System.out.println("Value from dp1 : "+ val);
    }
    
    public void dp2(String val) {
        System.out.println("Value from dp2 : "+ val);
        Assert.assertEquals(true, true);
    }
}
```